# Using TinyPic.com (or another site) to store user's images in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, storage

I'm writing an iphone app and don't really have the resources to rent sql server space to store user's pictures.

Is there another way?   Could a site like TinyPic.com be used?

What objective-c code could I use to send/store a picture there... and then later retrieve it as needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a list of sites for this purpose: imageshack, yfrog, tinypic. You have to choose carefully because each site has different usage allowance. Some sites allow you to upload a big image, some site don't. Some sites allow you to upload an infinite number of images, some don't.

About the code, usually, they have an API that you have to call to do the job. And for the return, they have a nice XML-Structured format that you have to parse. Look at [Imageshack API](http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/ImageshackAPI) for an example. My current project uses this

Comment: None of the sites show even a hint of "how to do this in C or Objective-C" or "on the iphone".

Comment: Which site would you suggest for "most traffic, most images, most dependable"?  Sounds like you favor imageShack?

Comment: Ops, you don't know how to call a http request and pass parameter, do you? You need to make a http request supply the parameter like the API said. You need to look up NSMutableURLRequest and NSUrlConnection .

Comment: Here is some limitation of imageshack: Images: less than 1.5MB.
Video: less than 50MB.
Files are deleted after 1 year of no access.
Each hot-linked image is limited to a bandwith of less than 300MB per hour.

Comment: My colleague decided to choose this service, then we went. I didn't do a whole research on that. I can say that imageshack is ok but I don't prefer it over other services

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image you wish to send to ImageShack already stored in an NSData object.
You just need to use NSUrlConnection to call:

http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php?myName=Patty&myPassword=test&image=myData

(That's just pseudo-code.  You can find the real link and parameters at:

http:// code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/ImageshackAPI